# How do I make sure my file is a video file?

Tags: files, copy, file-type

How can I copy video files from a directory and rest assured that the file I copied was a video file and not something else with a video extension like ".mp4"?

Comment: I would assume there is some metadata in the file that you can check, but I'm not overly familiar with the `mp4` file format. But think metadata, not extension.

Answer (score 5):

If you run the `file` command on the mp4 file it should identify it as an mp4 file if it really is one...

If I download an [example mp4 file](https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4) and run `file` on it I get this...

```
$ file file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4
file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
```

If the file isn't an mp4 file, even if it has an mp4 extension then `file` will identify it as something else.

Comment: Good and simple solution!

Comment: maybe helpful for use in script https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179898/find-file-by-magic-pattern-maching